# confirm dialog in jquery doesnt work correctly

Tags: jquery

i have the following code :

```
        $("[data-toggle='toggle']").bootstrapToggle({
            on: 'Active',
            off: 'Inactive',
            size: 'mini',
            width: 100,
            onstyle: 'success',
            offstyle: 'danger'
        });

        $(document).on('change', 'input:checkbox.status-change', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                const company_id = $(this).parent('tr').attr('id');
                const status = $(this).prop('checked');

                $.ajax({
                        url: 'customers/config/change_status.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            companyID: company_id,
                            status: status
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        console.log("fail");
                    })

            } else {}
        })
```

and the toggle (with bootstrapToggle())

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" class="status-change">
```

but when I click on toggle confirm dialog pops up and even after clicking on cancel it will change but the ajax wont run. but when I click second time 2 confirm dialogs will pop up with the same behaviour. After that it just pops few dialogs but nothing works.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

So i have found the answer.

Adding the following just after confirming dialog

```
                if (status == true) {
                    $(this).data('bs.toggle').on(true);
                } else {
                    $(this).data('bs.toggle').off(true);
                }
```

This has also been referenced in [here](https://github.com/minhur/bootstrap-toggle/issues/24) on github